# Why L'Hospital Rule cannot apply in calculating $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{(\cos {\frac{1}{x}} + \sin {\frac{1}{x^2}})^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital

Determine the limit of the following:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{(\cos {\frac{1}{x}} + \sin {\frac{1}{x^2}})^{x^2}}$$
I use the logarithm of exponential function to evaluate the above:
Let $u=\frac 1 x$, then
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}{(\cos {\frac{1}{x}} + \sin {\frac{1}{x^2}})^{x^2}}=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\exp(\frac{\ln(\cos u+\sin u^2) }{u^2})$$
Since the above expression is an indeterminate form of $\frac 0 0$, I use **L'Hospital Rule** to evaluate, and obtain the following result
$$-\frac{1}{2u (\sin u^2+\cos u)(\sin u-2u\cdot \cos u^2)}\rightarrow \frac 10$$ which is not true. What is my error when using L'Hospital Rule? Or there are some way to obtain the result above without using L'Hospital rule?

Comment: How did you get $u^2$ in the denominator in the first place? Raising to $1/x^2$ would be the same as raising to $u^2$ so you should have $\lim \exp(u^2\log(\cos u+\sin u^2))$ rather than a fraction.

Comment: You can apply L'Hospital's Rule directly without changing to $u$. Also note the mistake pointed out by @HenningMakholm.

Comment: I apologised for mistyped the problem. Now I have made an edit to it.

Comment: You missed another $1/x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\ln(\cos u+\sin u^2)}{u^2}\rightarrow\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{2u\cos u^2-\sin u}{2u(\cos u+\sin u^2)}$$

$$=\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{2\cos u^2-\dfrac{\sin u}u}{2(\cos u+\sin u^2)}=\dfrac{2-1}{2(1+0)}$$

Comment: Oh I understand now. I mistakenly put the term $2u \cos u^2 - \sin u$ on the denominator.

Comment: @weilam06, See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051285/prove-lim-limits-x-to-infty-left-sin2-left-frac1x-right-cos-frac1x/3052780#3052780

Answer (score 0):

Using the rules of L'Hospital we get $$e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}1/2\,{\frac {\sin \left( {x}^{-1} \right) x-2\,\cos \left( {x}^{-2}
 \right) }{{x}^{4} \left( \cos \left( {x}^{-1} \right) +\sin \left( {x
}^{-2} \right)  \right) }}}=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to evaluate
$$
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(\cos(u)+\sin(u^2))}{u^2}
$$
The derivative of the numerator is
$$
\frac{-\sin(u)+2u\cos(u^2)}{\cos(u)+\sin(u^2)}
$$
because the derivative of $\ln(f(x))$ is $f'(x)/f(x)$ and not $1/(f'(x)f(x))$ as you wrote instead.

It's easier with a Taylor expansion:
$$
\cos(u)+\sin(u^2)=1-\frac{u^2}{2}+u^2+o(u^2)=1+\frac{u^2}{2}+o(u^2)
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(\cos(u)+\sin(u^2))}{u^2}=
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u^2/2+o(u^2))}{u^2}=
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{u^2/2+o(u^2)}{u^2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$